# Waiting for WebBrowser ajax content

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, browser

I want to pause the execution of my thread until a particular div has been loaded via ajax into a WebBrowser instance. Obviously I can continuously check for the presence of this div doing something like:

```
while (Browser.Document.GetElementById("divid") == null) { Thread.Sleep(200); }
```

However, sleeping the thread that the Browser is in between loops only blocks the browser from actually loading the content in the first place. It seems, therefore, that I need to execute the `Browser.Navigate` method in a separate thread - I can then continue to check/wait for the presence of the div whilst the WebBrowser instance continues loading the URL I asked it to.

My attempts at this, however, have failed and I'd value any input on how I should go about this. I thought simply dispatching a new thread with `new Thread(() => { Browser.Navigate(url); });` would work but after doing so, nothing loads and the Browser.ReadyState remains as 'Uninitialized'. I presume I'm misunderstanding how to go about properly threading procedures like this with C# and would value some advice!

Comment: Refer [WebBrowser control = wait for page load to complete](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/9e5d265c-8771-433c-a2aa-91b4eeb1d684/webbrowser-control-wait-for-page-load-to-complete-in-an-assembly?forum=winforms). It says - call `System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents ()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't block the main thread's message pump. Since the browser is an STA component, xmlhttprequest won't be able to raise events from the background thread if you block the message pump.
You can't navigate in a background thread. The Windows Forms wrapper of the webbrowser ActiveX does not support access from other threads than the UI thread. Use a timer instead.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the timer approach? Can we add a delay of 1 second before firing the DocumentCompleted Event?

Comment: No, but you can starter a timer then parse the document in its tick event, assuming the ajax operation finishes before the timer ticks. Remember to stop the timer when you are done parsing.

Answer (score 7):

The following should work,

```
while (Browser.Document.GetElementById("divid") == null) 
{ 
    Application.DoEvents();
    Thread.Sleep(200); 
}
```

The above worked for me...

Comment: I did experiment with something similar but in the end used Sheng Jiang's method. It seemed to be the more 'correct' way to do it.

Comment: what if the div not fully loaded?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a text into body for example:

```
while (HtmlWindow.Document.Body.InnerHtml.Contains(some_text) == false)
{        
    Application.DoEvents();
    Thread.Sleep(200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not call `Thread.Sleep` as it will block the UI thread.

A better solution is to create an asynchronous task. Inside this task you can call `Task.Delay` which won't interfere with the UI.

```
static async Task<IHTMLElement> WaitForElement(WebBrowser browser, string elementID, TimeSpan timeout)
{
    long startTime = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
    var timeoutMS = timeout.TotalMilliseconds;

    // While the timeout has not passed...
    while (DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds() - startTime < timeoutMS)
    {
        // Wait for 200ms
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200));

        // Check if the document contains the element
        var document = (HTMLDocument) browser.Document;
        var element = document.getElementById(elementID);
        if (element != null)
        {
            // Element found, stop looping
            return element;
        }
    }

    throw new Exception($"Element was not loaded after {timeoutMS} milliseconds");
}
```

The code above checks the DOM every 200 milliseconds to see if the element with the given ID exists. It also contains a timeout (e.g. 10 seconds) in case the element never gets loaded for any unexpected reason.

Here is an example showing how to use this function to read the value out of a text field added to the document after an AJAX call:

```
var input = (IHTMLInputElement) await WaitForElement(myBrowserControl, "input-id", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
var value = input.value; // Read the value of the input field
```